# How to colorize Elixir iex prompt?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

Is it possible to add color and other effects to the [`iex`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html) prompt? Does `iex` have a resource file (like [`.irbrc`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration) for Ruby's [`irb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell))? Is there a customization API that allows prompt customization (like Ruby's [`IRB.conf`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Customizing+the+IRB+Prompt))?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, yes, and yes!

To customize your prompt, you'll need several things:

- An `.iex.exs` file in your home directory. Create this file if it doesn't exist. It will be executed when [`iex`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html) launches.
- *[optional]* A call to [`Application.put_env`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html#put_env/4) to enable ANSI. You may need this if `iex` on your platform (e.g., Windows 10) does not detect ANSI support.
- A call to [`IEx.configure`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html#configure/1) to enable color and set the prompt.
- *[ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to correct the cursor position*. Without this, using up/down arrows to cycle through command history moves the cursor ever farther to the right. [`IO.ANSI`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/IO.ANSI.html) does not currently expose all the cursor movement codes, but raw codes will work for terminals that support them.
- `IO.ANSI` formatting functions.
- Prompt text.
- `IO.ANSI.reset` to turn off any remaining formatting.
- Convert to a string with `IO.chardata_to_string`.

Here's what works for me with `iex` 1.3.0 in Terminal and [iTerm2 3.0.3](https://www.iterm2.com/version3.html) on OS X 10.11.5 and in Console, [GitBash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), and [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) on Windows 10:

```
# ~/.iex.exs
Application.put_env(:elixir, :ansi_enabled, true)
IEx.configure(
  colors: [enabled: true],
  default_prompt: [
    "\e[G",    # ANSI CHA, move cursor to column 1
    :magenta,
    "%prefix", # IEx prompt variable
    ">",       # plain string
    :reset
  ] |> IO.ANSI.format |> IO.chardata_to_string
)
```

This code works pretty well, but my prompt only takes effect after the first interaction: when `iex` first launches, it shows its builtin prompt. If I hit return, then my prompt goes into effect.  If anyone knows how to fix that, please share.

[UPDATED: modified to work better on Windows.]

Comment: IEx.configure colors: [ eval_result: [ :green, :bright ] ]   # I wonder why green shows as yellow?

Comment: @sheriffderek ANSI color names map to indexes in a color table defined elsewhere (e.g., in a terminal program.) Many terminal programs support color schemes (e.g., https://github.com/lysyi3m/osx-terminal-themes)

Comment: on Windows 10 the location of the config file is `%USERPROFILE%\.iex.exs`

Comment: What comes in place of %USERPROFILE%??

Comment: just in case, one uses multiple windows terminals, e.g. ConEmu/Cmder and plain cmd/VSCode, which cannot do ANSI, the config can be made conditional, e.g. `if System.get_env("ConEmuANSI") == "ON" do ... end`

Comment: The `"\e[G"` seems incompatible with Elixir 1.15.6 - it causes `(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :prim_tty.cols/2`